# When rows of a resultset are generated?

Tags: mysql

Consider a client which asks MySQL server for 100000 rows, but retrieves rows later one-by-one.

Does MySQL server generate the entire resultset before sending to client, or does it generate rows during sending to the client?

When most memory is used by the server: when generating the resultset or when sending it to the client?

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL needs to create a temporary table it generates the result before sending it to a client.

Normally you want to avoid that and make Mysql to generate the result as it accesses the table(s) and as fast as the client reads it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the network transmission of the resultset?

Either way is possible.  There is a setting on the connection; the details depend on what API you are using.

I think all APIs default to "all at once".  This is minimal impact on the network, the server, etc.  And it gets to the last row fastest.

The "one row at a time" (which might be several at a time under the covers) leads to a lot of network chatter, gives you the first row sooner, but takes longer.

What are you going to do with 100000 rows?  Display them?  I suspect not.  Put them into an array in your PHP/Java/VB client?  Watch out, you may run out of RAM.  Count the rows?  Then you should have used `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

My point is, that you will almost never be asking for a huge resultset.  And if you do, you should probably break it up for reasons that don't relate to MySQL.

Or are you asking about transactional integrity?  And "transaction isolation modes", where in you can effectively get all the rows at some instant in time with the right mode.  That gets into the details of MVCC.